# Recommended books on Mediation Analysis?

Tags: references, causality, mediation

I am interested in self learning Mediation Analysis. I have an MSc in Statistics, and I was wondering what would be an appropriate textbook to dig into this area. I would like something that combines theory and applications, perhaps with focus on the theory and assumptions.

Comment: There are plenty of online resources. The wiki article links several high quality articles, like originating work by Baron Kenny, and Sobel. Pearl has some white papers on mediation from a causality perspective.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://afhayes.com/introduction-to-mediation-moderation-and-conditional-process-analysis.html) is one of the best books on this topic by Andrew Hayes. He has written a process macro for SPSS. You can refer that for practical purposes.